# How to use commands inside Shell function while having quotes and semicolon

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell

I have borrowed below code from the google and modified it a little but somehow it not giving the expected output.

**Shell function:**

```
remote_collect() {
    target_host=$1
    {
        read -r rhelInfo
        read -r perlInfo
    } < <(
          ssh -i my_connect "root@${target_host}" \
              -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no \
              /bin/bash <<-EOF
              cat /etc/redhat-release | awk 'END{print \$7}'
              #rpm -qa --last | awk '/kernel-[0-9]/'|head -1
              rpm -qa --last | awk '/kernel-[0-9]/{ first=$1; $1=""; print $0 }'
EOF
          ) 2>/dev/null
```

**Where is Problem:**

In the above function the command `rpm -qa --last | awk '/kernel-[0-9]/{ first=$1; $1=""; print $0 }'` does not produce anything while running as an script however if i use `rpm -qa --last | awk '/kernel-[0-9]/'|head -1` then this works perfectly, So, where i am missing something like escaping something?

Please help to make me understand or resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape all the `$` sequence in Order to work, and it should work.

Please try below.

```
rpm -qa --last | awk '/kernel-[0-9]/{ first=\$1; \$1=""; print \$0 }'
```